# JavaScript code doesn't allow dots to be entered, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html

In my JavaScript code, there's this part that checks if there are no special characters in the input box, but it doesn't allow dots (periods) to be entered. How do I change the code to accept dots to be entered?

```
re = /^\w+$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
  alert("Error: je naam mag alleen letters,nummers, en underscores bevatten!");
  form.username.focus();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
re = /^[\w.]+$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
   alert("Error: je naam mag alleen letters,nummers, en underscores bevatten!");
   form.username.focus();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy one of the other answers?

Answer (score 2):

**[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/U8OEQS/1)**.

You could allow the `.` using group `[]` :

```
re = /^[\w.]+$/;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
re = /^[\w.]+$/;
function test(input) {
    var result = re.test(input) ? "Pass" : "Fail";
    console.log(input + " : " + result);
}

test("word.");
test("word");
test("word,word");
test("word.word");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `re = /^\w+$/;` is a regular expression (RegEx).

- `\w` means alphanumeric characters.
- `^` means "starts with".
- `$` means "ends"
- `+` means one or more repetition.

So the RegEx will pass any value that starts with an alphanumeric character, ends with alphanumeric character and is at least 1 character long.

The `.` is not a valid alphanumeric characters, so you need to allow it also.

Change to `re = /^[\w\.]+$/;` and dots will be allowed too. (the `\.` is to escape the `.` character, because it has special meaning in RegEx).

Also, search about regex in google, that is a very powerful and useful tool for input validation.

Answer (score -1):

try this regexp:

```
re = /^\w*\.*\w*$/;
```

this will allow any number of characters (0-infinity) any number of dots followed by 0 or more characters.

you can use https://regex101.com/ for regexp testing.